# Should I replace with 8sp or upgrade to 9 speed? Or 10 speed?

Tags: gears, shifter, replacement

The original shifters that came with my 2001 Kona Blast MTB is gone. Also, the cassette and chain are long over due for replacement.

Hence, was think of dropping the 8 speed (3×8) altogether for the following reasons:

1. Limited options for replacement parts compared to 9sp or 10sp.
2. Replacement parts even when available are only limited to either the lower range .. or from other compatible brands.
3. Curiosity/vanity

Currently, will likely to use it mainly for my food delivery job.

I'm also planning to use this bike for touring (few days to 2 weeks). So would prefer to be able to get replacements easily at bike shops in the nearest town.

The reasons holding me back are:
 1.  I was told that 8sp chain and cassette are thicker therefore more durable.
 2. Really cheap to overhaul

9sp and 10sp are about the same price, so I still contemplating which would be better.

Am leaning more towards to 10 since it seemed to be the most common currently.

Would like to hear your opinions on should I just stay at 8sp or upgrade to 9sp or 10sp.

Comment: Well, that's not really possible to answer from a neutral point of view. That's what we need for a proper Q and A form here. Hence a closing vote from me as well. Opinions in comments though might help you.

Comment: You've already have a good idea of the facts. 9 speed is often considered a sweet spot. Not much gain in range or increment going to 10 (for triple that is).

Comment: Note going from eight to nine/ten also needs a different hub.

Comment: @gschenk freehub width for 8, 9, 10 should be the same, 7 speed freehubs are narrower I think

Comment: If you go to 10 speed you will likely need a new crank because of chain width and chainring spacing differences.

Comment: It also depends how competent you are with tools.  Getting a LBS to do all this could cost as much as a new bike due to labour charges.   That said I increased one bike from 1x6 to 3x8 and another from 3x5 to 3x9.  The OLD is the critical make/break point.